# Can anyone identify the manufacturer of this spigot

Tags: outdoor

[image]

Who is the manufacturer of this outdoor spigot? Can probably pack stem as that is where it is leaking but would like to just replace both seals.

Comment: Try doing a "gravestone rubbing" with a soft pencil on some paper - there appear to be letters just above the symbol/logo but I can't quite make them out. Also, where in the world is this spigot located (which tends to affect likely manufacturers.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually all seals used are standard, and not manufacturer specific.

Take them out and go shopping.

You have regular garden hose seal (probably 3/4 inch)

Then you have a o-ring type seal at valve on top.

You also have a seal inside the valve, usually with hole in the middle to screw it to the valve. Then you have teflon tape around the body of the valve.

Comment: Thank you for all the info. I also tried the "gravestone rub" but no luck on it.  Early 80s in Dallas, Tx area.